# Magento Search Between Attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product, frontend

Thanks for your time! I'm currently trying to figure out how to sort between my attribute on the frontend. For instance, sizes. I have a range of sizes 14 to 36, but I only want to see products between sizes 24 and 26. Is there any way to do this? Is this a Magento feature that I overlooked? Any help would be great!